# javascript toggleclass not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

Below script was working fine until yesterday 9/4/2019

I found in many search result toggleClass isn't functioning properly after certain version of chrome.
Would anyone have any suggestion on how it should be changed?

I've tried related findings but it didn't work

```
    $(".special_list > li").unbind("mouseover")
        .unbind("mouseout")
        .bind("mouseover", function() {
                $(this).find(".ov_layer").toggleClass("on");
            }).bind("mouseout", function() {
                $(this).find(".ov_layer").toggleClass("on");
            });
```

toggleClass should bring up intended CSS page

Comment: Do the alternatives `addClass()` for mouseover and `removeClass()` for mouseout still work?

Comment: Please provide HTML to accompany your JS.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".special_list > li").unbind("mouseover")
        .unbind("mouseout")
        .bind("mouseover", function() {
                $(this).find(".ov_layer").addClass("on");
            }).bind("mouseout", function() {
                $(this).find(".ov_layer").removeClass("on");
            });
```

Comment: addClass & removeClass didn't work for me :(
FYI, it works fine in IE but not in chrome or firefox

Comment: i forgot to mention site's jquery version is 1.8.3, its very much outdated and i'm working to update em

Comment: addClass and removeClass should work in FF and Chrome. Hmmm

Comment: we end up switching it to completely different function to make it work but thank you for your recommendation.